# WordPress - how to create a true parent-child relationship between two custom post types

Tags: wordpress, parent-child, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I am building a website for a travelling company where I need a parent child relationship between a Trip and Packaged tours offered by the company to visit that place. **Trip** is parent and **Packaged tours** are children to it and this is an **1-many relationship**.

To achieve this I created two Custom Post Types (Trip and Package-Tour). In Trip I added Package-Tour as a Relationship field.

Then I added two Package Tours (**PT-A** and **PT-B**) and two Trips (**Trip-A** and **Trip-B**). I associated PT-A with Trip-A and PT-B with Trip-B.

The problem is both PT-A and PT-B are visible in both trip pages while I was expecting only the associated one to come up.

In my `single.php` I have written this code block:

```
<?php
    $packages = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'package_tour',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'key' => 'available_tour_packages',
            'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    ));

    if($packages) {
      foreach($packages as $package) {
         echo "<h1>" . $package->post_title . "</h1>";
         echo "<p>" . $package->trip_itinerary . "</p>";
         echo "<p>" . $package->booking_procedure . "</p>";
      }
    }
?>
```

`echo`-ing `get_the_ID` gives me correct `ID` of Trip post but in the database I saw that values saved under `post_parent` Package-Tour posts are all 0 (not the ID of Trip post), which mean that current relationship is not a true parent-child relationship - the way I thought.

I have started WordPress very recently and don't have much experience of it yet. What is the correct way of doing this?

**Update:**

This is how the Trips and Package tours are linked with each other. One trip with one package tour. But both packages (A and B) are showing up on Trip-A and Trip-B pages when Trip-A should show Package-A and Trip-B should show Package-B.

[image]

Comment: why use quotes around `'"' . get_the_ID() . '"'` ?

Comment: I removed the quotes but no luck :(

Comment: How are you linking the package tours with the trips? Is it a selection with custom field key `available_tour_packages` ? And is there any data? Or is the data returned differently than an ID?

Comment: Yes, it is a selection with custom filed key `available_tour_packages`. There are two records under custom post type Tour Packages (`tour_packages`). Means the hierarchy is now like Trip -> tour_package (one for each trip, I have two different trips).

Comment: Data is returned as `Post Object` for Tour Package not as ID.

Comment: In that case can you try: `'compare' => 'IN'` (source: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/meta-query-for-post-object/)

Comment: Already tried but no change!

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the quotes in the meta_query, because the value stored is an integer. Try:

```
$packages = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'package_tour',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key' => 'available_tour_packages',
        'value' => get_the_ID(),
        'compare' => 'IN'
    )
));
```